# Laptop not detecting one specific wifi network

Tags: windows-7, wifi-configuration, ubuntu-16.04

My laptop dualboots both ubuntu 16.04 and windows 7 and detects and connects to most wifi networks very easily on both operating systems.

However, there is a certain wifi network I cannot get my laptop to even detect. The network has multiple usernames and passwords, both of which are needed to connect. I have these credentials, but my laptop won't even detect. Other networks in the area are detected and can be connected to.

Comment: Does it work in the same frequency? There are multiple bands around, and many older Wi-Fi cards do not support the newer 5GHz networks.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Google the model of the network card (and see the router's capabilities and settings)

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to connect to the because of frequecy incompatibility .There are five distinct frequency ranges: 2.4 GHz, 3.6 GHz, 4.9 GHz, 5 GHz, and 5.9 GHz bands that are alowed.Laptops dont cover all, this might be a reason it doesnt connect.